# R column names as list instead of vector

Tags: r, arrays, list, dataframe

So names(df) returns a vector. How do I get the column names as a list instead of vector?

I thought this might work:

```
list(names(df)
```

but it doesn't.

There must be a simple way to covert column names to list data type.

Comment: `as.list(names(df))`

Comment: @SamR as simple as I hoped. TY.